# Radeditor issue with IE11

Tags: asp.net, telerik, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, radeditor

I have an aspx page for sending email which uses radeditor for creating the email body. In IE11 browser I type something by selecting font style, size and color. After that if I change any of the font controls the cursor goes back to the first line of the textbox. This is not a problem with IE8. I am having this problem only with IE11 windows 8.1 browser. Please help me out!

here is the aspx code

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="radEditor" SkinID="BasicSetOfTools" ToolsHeight="20px"
                        ToolsWidth="755px" Width="753px" Height="300px" Overflow="auto" DefaultColor="white"
                        saveinfile="False" ToolsFile="/includes/TelerikToolsFile.xml" EditModes="Design" StripFormattingOnPaste="MSWordNoFonts"
                        StripFormattingOptions="MSWordNoFonts" SpellCheckSettings-DictionaryPath="/RadControls/RadSpell/" SpellCheckSettings-DictionaryLanguage="en-US">
                    </telerik:RadEditor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for errors? IE11 tends to break with .NET4: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11.

Also, do things work fine in the demos they ahve: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx? If so, compare your setup with the demonstarted one and see what breaks things.